Dart get package name
I have Dart only project.
How to print the package name ?
For example:
package:myapp/something.dart

How to print this "myapp" from the Dart program itself ?
In other word, I am reffering to the first line of pubspec.yaml name: myapp
Tried
Platform.script; // => /absolute/path/to/the/script.dart
Directory.current; // => /absolute/path/to/the/working/directory

I found a solution with Dart Mirror using
class DummySelf {}

Then
String currentPackage () {
  final classMirror = reflectClass(DummySelf);
  final b = classMirror.location;
  final c = b.toString().replaceFirst("package:", "").split("/").first;
  return c;
}

But it is a very very very ugly solution, unless someone confirms it is the only solution

add yaml package in project and with the following code you can access the content of the pubspec.yaml
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';

Future<void> readPubspec() async {
  try {
    // Load the pubspec.yaml file as a string
    final File file = File('pubspec.yaml');
    final String yamlString = file.readAsStringSync();

    // Parse the string into a YamlMap
    final YamlMap yamlMap = loadYaml(yamlString);

    // Access specific content from the yamlMap
    print('Name: ${yamlMap['name']}');
    print('Version: ${yamlMap['version']}');
    print('Description: ${yamlMap['description']}');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error reading pubspec.yaml: $e');
  }
}


